# Changing method behavior depending source screen

Tags: flutter

I have a widget with this method in flutter that is called by two different screens, I would like 'Navigator.pop' to change its behavior depending on which screen calls it.
On the first screen it would apply a common 'pop', and on the second screen, for a specific route. Can you help me with this?

`

```
void salvarCartao(InputCartaoDto cartao, BuildContext context) async {
    var cartaoDto = await AdicionarCartaoCommand().execute(cartao, context);
    if (cartaoDto != null) {
      var usuarioCorrente = await ObterUsuarioCorrenteCommand().execute();
      var listaCartoes = usuarioCorrente?.cartoes;
      listaCartoes?.add(cartaoDto);
      AtualizarUsuarioCommand().execute(usuarioCorrente!);
    }
    //if screen 1 called the method:
    Navigator.pop(context);

    //if screen 2:
    Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/carrinho-pagamento'));

  }
```

`

I'm actually still learning flutter, I couldn't think of a solution with my current knowledge

Comment: in this method you just navigate back or another screen ?

Comment: Why don't you pass one more parameter to say which screen you are calling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then redefine your function. Ex:

```
    void salvarCartao(InputCartaoDto cartao, BuildContext context, int opt) async {
        var cartaoDto = await AdicionarCartaoCommand().execute(cartao, context);
        if (cartaoDto != null) {
          var usuarioCorrente = await ObterUsuarioCorrenteCommand().execute();
          var listaCartoes = usuarioCorrente?.cartoes;
          listaCartoes?.add(cartaoDto);
          AtualizarUsuarioCommand().execute(usuarioCorrente!);
        }
        //if screen 1 called the method:
       
       if(opt ==1)
        Navigator.pop(context);
       else
        //if screen 2:
        Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/carrinho-pagamento'));
    
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a flag to the salvarCartao function, depending on which screen calls it.

```
isFromScreen2 ? Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/carrinho-pagamento')) : Navigator.pop(context);
```

or

```
if (isFromScreen2) { 
      Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/carrinho-pagamento'))
   } else { 
      Navigator.pop(context); 
   }
```